# Opinions on Swift Migrator Helper Functions?

Tags: swift

Working with an old Swift 3 file converted to Swift 4.2 so I can learn about drag and drop: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1016-drag-and-drop-tutorial-for-macos. Several helper functions were added during the conversion and I'm wondering whether or not it is worth it to try and incorporate the helper funcions into the existing code. It looks complicated to me and perhaps unnecessary if there aren't any good reasons to do this. For example:

```
 let props = [convertFromNSBitmapImageRepPropertyKey(NSBitmapImageRep.PropertyKey.compressionFactor): Appearance.imageCompressionFactor]
```

Here is the helper function:

```
fileprivate func convertFromNSBitmapImageRepPropertyKey(_ input: NSBitmapImageRep.PropertyKey) -> String {
    return input.rawValue
}
```

Comment: You mean this function was auto-regenerated by the migration?

Comment: @Alexander - yes they are auto-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the APIs on `NSBitmapImageRep` that I know accept the properties in this type: `[NSBitmapImageRep.PropertyKey: Any]`

As you can see, they expect the keys to be `NSBitmapImageRep.PropertyKey`, not their `String` raw values, so I'm not even sure where using this helper would even make sense. The idiomatic way to write this would be:

```
let props: [NSBitmapImageRep.PropertyKey: Any] = [
    .compressionFactor: Appearance.imageCompressionFactor,
    .somethingElse: SomeOtherValue,
]
```

Comment: I would agree that some of this seems a little odd but apparently the migrator doesn't alter your old code except to add functions it thinks are needed to work with changes from Swift 3 to Swift 4.2. I haven't done much coding in a while so this is helpful rather than getting a load of errors and trying to figure out what's wrong. What I posted is just one example and there are many more in this project. Hopefully I can eventually change the old code to what it needs to be for Swift 4.2 but it will take some time.

Comment: @JamesH Yep, that's pretty normal. We don't really know how to write tools that auto-generate reasonable code. Making mechanic transformations like "just introduce a shim helper function everywhere" is much more straight-forward and reliable than "infer the original codes' semantics and rewrite it in the new most idiomatic way"